# Facing issue with default pagination in "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle" when table is empty

Tags: pagination, yajra-datatable

I am using "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0", but I am facing an issue. When there are rows in the table, the pagination works as expected. However, when the table is empty, a default pagination appears showing "Previous 1 2 3 4 5 … Next" like this.